# TinyXML-2 error loading file with stylesheet

Tags: c++, tinyxml2

I have a function to load a xml file with TinyXML-2 library (v4.0.1). It always work fine, but today I see a problem that I don't know how to solve.

When I load de file:

```
if ( doc.LoadFile ( "file.xml" ) != tinyxml2::XML_SUCCESS )
```

It never return `XML_SUCCESS`. I'm watching many files and I see that only fail when the file has this line:

```
<?xml-stylesheet ...
```

Without this line it works fine. Why it's happening? What can I do for solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: If it never returns XML_SUCCESS, what does it return?

Comment: It returns `XML_ERROR_PARSING_DECLARATION`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyXML2 does not support XML style sheets or document type definitions (DTDs)
From the documentation:

> TinyXML-2 doesn't parse or use DTDs (Document Type Definitions) or
>   XSLs (eXtensible Stylesheet Language.)

That is why the XML read of the file with the `<?xml-stylesheet ...` definition is failing. Try commenting out this section. TinyXML2 observes the XML comment syntax of `<!-- your comment -->`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I did, delete the line before read with TinyXML-2 and now it works fine. I didn't know it doesn't read stylesheets.

Comment: Yes TinyXML2 is great library but fast and light for this reason. Apache Xerces supports document type definitions (DTDs) and other features - not sure about style sheets. You may want to check that out if you need more XML parsing options.